# Unexpected result while working with Python dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following list:

*Note: My actual list contains many number of elements, this is just a subset of my list*

```
tags = ['DT', 'NN' , 'DT' , 'NN' , 'JJ', 'JJ' , 'NN', 'DT' , 'JJ' , 'DT' , 'NN']
Utags = set(tags)
```

Then, I created a nested Python dictionary using the following code. The reason I use the following code to create my nested dictionary structure is because other attempts failed. Gave me the error: too many values to unpack.

```
transition = {x: {} for x in Utags}
inner = {x: float(1) for x in Utags}
for x in Utags:
    transition[x] = inner
```

the resulting structure looks like this:

```
 {'DT': {'DT': 1.0, 'JJ': 1.0, 'NN': 1.0},
 'JJ': {'DT': 1.0, 'JJ': 1.0, 'NN': 1.0},
 'NN': {'DT': 1.0, 'JJ': 1.0, 'NN': 1.0}}
```

Now I ran a loop which gave me unexpected result; I am trying to count the number of bigrams there are in the list 'tags'. for example, count the number of 'NN' there are followed by 'DT' in the list 'tags' and store the count value in transition['DT']['NN'].

My loop :

```
for i in Utags:
    for j in Utags:
        for k in xrange(0, len(tags) - 1):
            if((tags[k] == i) and (tags[k+1] == j)):
                count += 1
        transition[i][j] = count
        count = 0
```

The result is:

```
 {'DT': {'DT': 2, 'JJ': 2, 'NN': 2},
  'JJ': {'DT': 2, 'JJ': 2, 'NN': 2},
  'NN': {'DT': 2, 'JJ': 2, 'NN': 2}}
```

What's happening is, the count value is being filled in the entire dictionary instead of just

```
 transition[i][j]
```

How do I fix this bug?

Also, I noticed, If I manually create the dictionary structure without running the loop, the programs runs correctly.

Comment: Your outer dictionary contains many references to the same inner dictionary. That's why you're seeing the same info everywhere.

Comment: So what is the right way to create my nested dictionary structure??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the dictionary `inner` inside the `for` loop, because right now you always assign the same dict.

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the inner dictionary, otherwise you are storing the same reference everywhere. Like this:

```
templ = dict((i, 1.0) for i in Utags)
result = dict((key, templ.copy()) for key in templ)
```

This way you create a copy of the inner array, instead of just referencing it